# What is the correct phrase for "shortened words"?

Tags: phrase-requests

What I'm referring to is sometimes called slang, but I wanted to know if there is an actual name for these kinds of words.

For example, some words might be

- Admin (Administration)
- Fridge (Refrigerator)
- Uni (University)

I was thinking they were abbreviations, but the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation) on abbreviations seems to say otherwise

> An abbreviation (from Latin brevis, meaning short) is a shortened form of a word or phrase. It consists of a group of letters taken from the word or phrase. For example, the word abbreviation can itself be represented by the abbreviation abbr., abbrv. or abbrev.

Comment: Is "truncation" what you're after?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of several words, or a phrase, might suit your purposes. Omitting 'contraction' (see another answer):

> **stump word**: a word formed by abbreviating a single longer one, esp. by reducing it to a single syllable (freq. the first) or the minimum necessary for understanding.
>
> **clipping**: The shortening of a word, etc.; also, the resulting shortened form.
>
> **syncopation** or **syncope**: Contraction of a word by omission of one or more syllables or letters in the middle; transf., a word so contracted.
>
> **shrivel** (noun) Something shrivelled up ... a contracted word.

The list above omits the obsolete and rare words 'decurtation', 'accurtation' and 'paresis'.

(All definitions from [OED Online](http://oed.com/).)

Comment: +1 for *clipping* especially, the aptest term yet offered for the specific phenomenon in question.

Answer (score 5):

You call it "[***contraction***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contraction)" as it means:

> The process of shortening a word by combination or elision.

Example sentences:

‘The contraction of a phrase, word, or part of a word, has the analogy of a telescope being closed: biodegradable for biologically degradable; sitcom for situation comedy.’

‘Yes, since time immemorial, either/or have been as close as two words can get without contraction.’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]